# Ruby on Rails Net HTTP or HTTPParty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've been at this for awhile.  I've tried using net http to connect to a https url with no luck.  I've tried http party and getting uninitialized constant httpparty.  I am running rails 3.2.7.  I have httpparty add to gem file.

Can someone please provide an example with either problem sending params to a https url and receiving a response.

code:

```
options = {:id => params[:id], :code => params[:code]}
response = HTTPParty.post('https://test.com', options)
```

gem file:

```
gem "httparty", "~> 0.9.0"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
HTTParty.get('https://google.com', :query => {:q => 'stack overflow'})
```

If this doesn't work for you, please show the code you're using. It you're getting an uninitialized constant error, you've done something wrong. Did you run `bundle` after adding to your Gemfile?

Also, it's `HTTParty`, not `HTTPParty`.

Comment: :) okay, that fixes that problem

Comment: It still kill the server though

Comment: what do you mean by kill the server?